# Static resource not able to access global merged fields

Tags: visualforce, javascript, static-resources, global-variables

```
{!$Component.idPageTestCase.idForm.idFocusedTab}
```

This works well when it is there in Javascript tag inside visualforce page, but fails when the Javascript is moved to a static resource and the static resource is referenced in the page like below:

```
<apex:includeScript loadOnReady="true" value="{!URLFOR($Resource.TestRes, 'JS/Test.js')}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found out that to use global merged fields we have to use it like this:

// Define this in your page.

```
window.$Component = window.$Component || {};
$Component.idFocusedTab = '{!$Component.idPageTestCase.idForm.idFocusedTab}';
```

Then use this in your static resource  : `$Component.idFocusedTab`